# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Class '\App\Admin' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel-5.7. i am making multi auth system  I'm getting the following error

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Class '\App\Admin' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have Model class called Admin in the App folder, then you are calling it somewhere in the controller.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Admin extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Your controller will be

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class YourController extends Controller
{
   //Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error that you get. You either don't have a class in your `app` directory named `Admin` or you don't have the `namespace` on top of your class.

```
<?php namespace App;

class Admin 
{

}
```

or if your error is in a different class then you need to import it on top.

```
...
use PATH_TO_THE_ADMIN;

class YourClass {}
```

Comment: The problem is because you don't include your App\Admin class model in the class you are calling.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times when your class is not found, is basically as a result of not importing your namespace or typo error. so checke the two before anything else